# Why does nvcc fail allow casting a pointer of type T * to void *?

Tags: cuda, nvcc

With the following trivial deleter

```
struct CudaDeleter{ void operator()(void * ptr) { cudaFree( ptr ); } };
```

I get the following errors when using the deleter in code compiled with nvcc. The same deleter works fine with the vs2012 compiler

```
warning : "std::unique_ptr<_Ty, _Dx>::unique_ptr(
const std::unique_ptr<_Ty, _Dx>::_Myt &)
[with _Ty=const int, _Dx=cuda::CudaDeleter]"

error : function "cuda::CudaDeleter::operator()"
cannot be called with the given argument list

warning : "std::unique_ptr<_Ty, _Dx>::unique_ptr(
const std::unique_ptr<_Ty, _Dx>::_Myt &)
[with _Ty=float, _Dx=cuda::CudaDeleter]"
```

@talonmies: smart pointers are constructed with this function only

```
template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T, CudaDeleter> make_unique(size_t size)
{
    void * pMemory = nullptr;
    check( cudaMalloc(&pMemory, size) );
    return std::unique_ptr<T, CudaDeleter>( static_cast<T*>(pMemory) );
}
```

Comment: The nvcc compiler seems to have too many of these strange quirks, another one would be failure to support range-for, failure to give proper errors when templates fail... Would it be best to compile as little code as possible with the nvcc compiler?

Comment: It is a pretty self explanatory error - you are passing a C++ smart pointer to the deleter function, and it expects `void *`. Don't blame the compiler.....

Comment: no, I am passing the deleter function to the smart pointer upon construction of the said smart pointer

Comment: Does nvcc support unique_ptr of c++11? You may have to enable c++11 feature for nvcc/gcc when using unique_ptr. On the other hand, `void*` is c-style code. `template<class T> struct CudaDeleter{ void operator()(T* ptr){...}}` may be a better deleting functor for unique_ptr.

Comment: The thing is that nvcc *isn't a compiler*. It doesn't compile code, and it isn't compiling this code, the host compiler is (so vs2012 in this case). What it does do is steer compilation and set compiler arguments. It is possible that c++11 support is being disabled by compiler options, but that is about all that could be happening.

Comment: @talonmies, that would be rather confusing as things like auto works fine

Answer (score 5):

The following works for me. Try the standalone code below, if it works then you need to identify the difference with your code, if not, then there's something different about your setup.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct CudaDeleter
{
    void operator()(void *p)
    {
        std::cout << "Free..." << std::endl;
        cudaError_t res = cudaFree(p);
        if (res != cudaSuccess)
        {
            std::cout << "Error freeing: " << cudaGetErrorString(res) << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T, CudaDeleter> make_unique(size_t size)
{
    void *pMemory = nullptr;
    std::cout << "Allocate..." << std::endl;
    cudaError_t res = cudaMalloc(&pMemory, size);
    if (res != cudaSuccess)
    {
        std::cout << "Error allocating pMemory: " << cudaGetErrorString(res) << std::endl;
        throw;
    }
    return std::unique_ptr<T, CudaDeleter>(static_cast<T*>(pMemory));
}

int main(void)
{
    {
        std::cout << "Create..." << std::endl;
        std::unique_ptr<float, CudaDeleter> x = make_unique<float>(100*sizeof(float));
        std::cout << "Destroy..." << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Done." << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue I was having, in the end it was a mistake on my part

It is not that any T * cannot be cast into a void * but const T * cannot be cast into void *.

Furthermore a pointer to const cannot be freed by cudaFree, which means that Eric's suggestion of

```
template<class T> struct CudaDeleter{ void operator()(T* ptr){...}}
```

Will not work.

Something like this will work though

```
template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<typename std::remove_const<T>::type, CudaDeleter> make_unique(size_t size)
{
    typename std::remove_const<T>::type * pMemory = nullptr;
    check( cudaMalloc(&pMemory, size) );
    return std::unique_ptr<typename std::remove_const<T>::type, CudaDeleter>( pMemory );
}
```